# How to vertically stack ListView's with one ListView expanded

Tags: dart, flutter

I am building a simple Flutter app with two `ListView`'s on top of each other. I'm trying to position the first list view (a list of files), which takes up all available space, to be above the second list view (a list of tags), which just takes up the necessary space to display the tags.

[Here is a mockup of the desired design (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf1aL.png)

I have tried adding the lists to a `Stack` widget, but the lists overlap. I have also tried adding the `ListView`'s to two `Expanded` widgets but this also does not work.

[This is what my app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCn1G.png) using the `Stack` widget.

Here is all the code used (copy and paste into  default project `main.dart` if you want to run it)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return new ListTile(
                title: new Text("File $index"),
              );
            },
          ),
          new Text("Tags"),
          new ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return new Chip(label: new Text("Tag $index"));
            }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone know how to make this layout in Flutter [where you have two vertical `ListView`'s with some space between them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf1aL.png)?

Answer (score 2):

Use a CustomScrollView with multiple SliverLists inside:

```
  CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(List<Text>.generate(7, (int i) {
          return Text("List 1 Item $i");
        })),
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Text('Tags'),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(List<Text>.generate(3, (int i) {
          return Text("List 2 Item $i");
        })),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Comment: Just tried that, using `Column` and `Expanded` doesn't stack the second below the first, instead it shows both on the screen with ListView1 taking up 70% of the screen and the second taking up 30% of the screen.

E.g., if there are 100 files in `ListView1`, the user should scroll down to see `ListView2`, but with this approach both `ListView1` and `ListView2` will be visible at the same time.

Comment: I think now I got what you want. Maybe its the `shrinkWrap` property, let me test it out.

Comment: Editted the answer with the correct solution. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried it and it's nearly what I want. Basically I want `List 1` to take up the empty space like an `Expanded` would do, and get `List 2` right after it on the bottom. I took a screenshot to explain [https://i.imgur.com/QfuKLvQ.png](https://i.imgur.com/QfuKLvQ.png) better after running your solution.

Comment: `SliverFillRemaining` (which fills up the empty space if it's available) nearly does what I want but then it says "there is never any room for anything beyond this sliver" so I couldn't add the second list widget.